# Lots of AppleSimpleUARTSync::resetTxQueue: _txInterruptRunning

Tags: macos, wifi, high-sierra

My Wi-Fi of my MacBook is really unstable since the month December, I also get a lot of errors:

```
default 13:06:03.754394 +0100   kernel AppleSimpleUARTSync::resetTxQueue: _txInterruptRunning
```

(and of course the error `Month 13 is out of bounds`)

Does somebody knows what the first error is?

Comment: I get a constant floor of this error exactly when I stream music to my bluetooth speakers.

Comment: I log this message while I am streaming to my bluetooth speakers as well.